# Deep link only reopens the same screen and cannot add to the navigation stack

Tags: react-navigation

Currently in my application I have a screen that is connected to the deep links through react navigation. When I open this screen, background the application and then try to open a deep-link, react navigation opens the existing screen on the navigation stack.

I want the linking options to trigger a completely new page on top of the existing one and put it in the stack, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by specifying a `getId` function:

```js
<Stack.Screen
  name="Profile"
  component={ProfileScreen}
  getId={({ params }) => params.userId}
/>
```

The `getId` function should return a unique ID to identify the screen - usually, the ID of the item shown in the screen, React Navigation will only reuse the screen if the ID is the same.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen/#getid